# WSO2 Identity Server caching after role change

Tags: caching, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I would like to share with you the levels of frustration that I experienced trying to fix a WSO2 issue that i had. 
I'm having a system with Api Manager and Identity Server working together. Api Manager is responsible for the apis, and Identity Server is in charge of users and roles authentication. Before accessing an api, a client receives a token from IS and sends it as a Bearer to the AM. Then the token is parsed on WSO2 AM end, and it reaches the api as a JWT (object with all the user's data).

It works well, until you try to switch a user from one role to another. In this case due to wso2 cache, it still passes the old role to the api for 15 minutes, which is causing issues.

For the first glance, the solution is very simple, right? Either refresh the cache or disable the cache from the config files.

However after investigating the "change role" procedure, I found that changing a role invokes a [method "removeGatewayKeyCache"](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/5.0.x/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/keymgt/listeners/KeyManagerUserOperationListener.java), that is supposed to remove the caching from the system. I don't know what it removes, but the cache was still there after the procedure. 
By the way, this method is cleaning the cache even when the GatewayKeyCache is set to false in ALL the possible configuration files!

So my approach to tackle the problem was to run a search on all the config files for the word "Cache" to identify the cache that I need to disable.
WSO2 AM & IS have dozens of configuration files, and most of them have some "Cache" setting, some of them duplicated in different files. I tried to disable all the relevant that I could find, so i set to false all these:

```
EnableGatewayKeyCache
EnableKeyMgtValidationInfoCache
EnableJWTCache
EnableOAuthCache
UserRolesCacheEnabled
AuthorizationCacheEnabled
GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled
```

But JWT token still contained the old cached user role for 15 minutes! And it still invoked "removeGatewayKeyCache" and removed some tokens from cache (I disabled it goddamn!).

My workaround was opening a carbon.xml configuration and setting the DefaultCacheTimeout param to 0.

```
<DefaultCacheTimeout>0</DefaultCacheTimeout>
```

This was the only trick that worked! So now I have a system without caching at all, but at least it works as expected.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your APIM version?

Comment: The AM is 1.10.0, IS - 5.1.0, the apimgt plugin is 5.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have disabled `EnableKeyMgtValidationInfoCache`, to generate JWT tokens per every call, as mentioned in [this document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Configuring+Caching#ConfiguringCaching-Keycache).

Comment: Yes, EnableKeyMgtValidationInfoCache is set to false too. Forgot to mention it. Will add it to the post now.